# I'm having problems to use my java eclipse's projects in Vscode

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code

I want to move to VsCode, I installed Java extension pack at VsCode and configured JDK to use Openj9,
but don't works, idk what to do anymore. Everytime I try run a Java project that I coded by Eclipse it don't run. A common error is

> Error: Could not find or load main class application.Program

Comment: The Eclipse created a package structure that vscode dosen't undertand, and has problems to catch dependencies

Comment: Actually, java extension needs jdk11 or more recent version to support, so if you set jdk9 as the value of the setting `java.home` in VS Code, it may throw some compilation errors. Install higher version and try again.